# Binding метода с параметрами на условиях

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Вот хотелось упростить код не много и у меня есть вот такой код XAML.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="LogToggleBtn" Click="LogToggleBtn_Click"/>
```

Вот такой C# код на клике ToggleBtn.

```
SetSettingsValue("LOGGING", LogToggleBtn.IsChecked == true ? "1" : "0");
```

Как это можно упростить что бы выполнить это без метода? В смысле вызывать этот метод с параметрами на условиях, но без C# кода.

Я практически ничего не знаю про MVVM, если можно то скиньте решение. :)

SetSettingsValue - Метод, принимает два аргумента, string и string. Для некоторых других элементов отведен точно такой же метод только с string и int.

Comment: Эээ, ничего не понятно, но можно написать команду и конвертер, но кода выйдет больше

Comment: @АндрейNOP Как не понятно? Объяснил же нужно вызвать метод, SetSettingsValue с параметрами String и String, и проверить, если Checkbox чекнут, то вызываем этот метод с параметрами "TEST" "0", а если чекнут "TEST" "1". Просто я думаю это можно сократить в XAML.

Comment: Сократить - это если изначально использовать MVVM, где можно в set нужного свойства засунуть вызов вашего метода, а из того что сейчас именно сократить, навряд ли выйдет.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.)